# My list won't clear, despite using Clear(), and it even keeps data after closing the form

Tags: c#

```
 private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtInput.Text = "";
        txtOutput.Text = "";

        mainList.Clear();
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamWriter outputFile;
        outputFile = File.AppendText("texter.txt");
        outputFile.WriteLine(txtInput.Text);
        outputFile.Close();

        List<String> mainList = new List<String>();

        StreamReader inputFile;
        inputFile = File.OpenText("texter.txt");
        while (inputFile.EndOfStream == false)
        {
            mainList.Add(inputFile.ReadLine());
        }
        inputFile.Close();

        for (int i = 0; i < mainList.Count; i++)
        {
            txtOutput.Text += Environment.NewLine + mainList[i];
        }


    }
```

This is pretty much my entire program, and the list in particular is bugging me.  When I hit add, it puts in every entry ever made onto the list into the text box.  Closing the form itself doesn't clear the list, and neither does my Clear button.

Comment: `List<String> mainList` in `btnAdd_Click` is a local variable. `mainList` in `btnClear_Click` is perhaps a class data member.

Comment: Ah it's not shown here since I only included the handlers, but I did declare the list as a global, with List<String> mainList = new List<String>();

Comment: remove the List<String> mainList = new List<String>(); in your btnAdd_Click, because it is making a new Instance of a List as a Inner Class Variable. The btnClear_Click is accessing the Global mainList Variable and clearing it, it won't clear your list.

Comment: Please provide [MCVE] - the code as posted can't compile as `List<String> mainList` is local variable of `btnAdd_Click` and not accessible in `btnClear_Click`

Answer (score 0):

From the comment it is clear that you have a Global variable `mainList` defined as `List<String> mainList = new List<String>();` Then within the Add_button click you are creating another List(having local [scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx) to the btnAdd_Click) and adding items to the list. This variable will not be available in `btnClear_Click` So actually what is happening here is Adding Values to one list and clearing another list.

What you can Do is:

- Remove   `List<String> mainList = new List<String>();` from `btnAdd_Click` if you don't want to clear the existing data before adding new items.
- Use `mainList = new List<String>();` in `btnAdd_Click` instead for `List<String> mainList = new List<String>();` if you need to clear the existing data before adding new items. Then your snippet will work as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

- You're clearing the global variable while it's empty.
- You're adding text to the local variable instead of adding it to the global
  variable.